# Sharepoint REST api search for a querytext in a site

Tags: search, site, api

I am having issue while searching using query text in a specific site. When I use following get query,
https://client.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='vpn',  I get results in the entire site of client.sharepoint.com
I also get results when I search for term 'vpn' directly in site https://client.sharepoint.com/sites/SysDocs. Now I need to combine both. 
When I use https://client.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='vpn+path:"https://client.sharepoint.com/sites/SysDocs"', it is not returning me results.

What should I change in the syntax for getting 'vpn' results in site https://client.sharepoint.com/sites/SysDocs ? Please advise !!

Thanks !!

Comment: can you try it as `https://cl‌​ient.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='(vpn)+AND+(path:https://client.sharepoint.com/sites/SysDocs)'` and check ?

Comment: Still getting same issue. No results returned.

Comment: How about `https://cl‌​ient.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=‌​'vpn AND path:htt‌​ps://client.sharepoi‌​nt.com/sites/SysDocs‌​'` ? It works at my end

Comment: I am still getting no results. In SharePoint query search tool, my query becomes like this
https://client.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='vpn+AND+path:htt‌​ps:%2f%2fclient.sharepoi‌​nt.com%2fsites%2fSysDocs‌​'
Not sure if I can pass you the screenshot but when I directly search vpn under the site on sharepoint, I get lot of results. So expecting this to return me results. I tried other search strings also but same result
This is office365 sharepoint api calls.

Comment: ok thats strange, i am using POSTMAN and its giving me correct results. Can you try hitting the query in the browser and check ?

Comment: Thank you so much Gautam !! Your syntax (vpn)+AND+(path:htt‌​ps://client.sharepoi‌​nt.com/sites/SysDocs‌​) is working.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your endpoint url as below :

```
https://cl‌​ient.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?
querytext=‌​'(vpn)+AND+(path:htt‌​ps://client.sharepoi‌​nt.com/sites/SysDocs‌​)'
```

or

```
https://cl‌​ient.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?
querytext=‌​‌​'vpn AND path:htt‌​ps://client.sharepoi‌​nt.com/sites/SysDocs‌​'
```

Comment: Have posted it as answer. Please accept it by checking the checkbox below the button or as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)